# How do i make the variable have multiple values, and have those values be valid in an input tag?

Tags: php

So I made a form password system, and I encountered this issue where I try to input the values in the array, the password is still wrong? ( I put "batanes" or "Batanes" into the input and submit, but it's not the right password for some reason. Even though its the exact value in the array)

```
<form id="pass"  method="POST">
            <b><label for="Pass"> Where is our Ultimate Travel Destination Wish List in the Philippines?   </label></b>
            <input id="Pass" name="Pass" type="text" placeholder="Enter Password Here..." required>
            <input type=submit> 

            <?php
            error_reporting(0);
                $pass= array("Batanes", "batanes");
                $enter= $_POST['Pass'];

                if ($enter === $pass) {
                    echo <<<EOL
                      $('<div class=overlay></div>').bind('mouseover',function(){
    });

    $(<div class="popup"> Good Job Man! <br> Now to the next! </div>).bind('mouseout', function(){              
    });

    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'mommysthirdimahe.html'; }, 2000);
    </script>
    EOL;
    exit;
    }
    elseif ($enter === NULL) {
     echo "";
     }
```

How do i make it so that the when the $enter is equal to the values in the $pass array, It does the functions in "if"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for the question is the [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

Example:

```
if (in_array($enter, $pass)) {
    // execute whatever you want
}
```

---

I noticed that you are storing the "Batanes" word twice in the `$pass` array, to handle the case sensitive check. Instead of this you can store the lowercase version only and convert the input to lowercase too using the [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function.

Example:

```
$pass = ['batanes'];
if (in_array(strtolower($enter), $pass)) {
    // execute whatever you want
}
```

However in this case you don't need the array anymore and you can simply just use this:

```
if ($pass === $enter) {
    // execute whatever you want.
}
```